# CAN Bus filter and mask arrangement

Tags: can-bus

I am trying to set my acceptance filters and masks but I could not do it properly. How should i set my mask and filters so that I will only accept messages from ID's  of 00001560 thru to 0000156F

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the CAN controller used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set filter to 00001560 and mask to  1FFFFFF0 so that you will only accept messages with ID's between  00001560 and 0000156F.
Kind regards.